# Error building Android project with NDK: Relocations in generic ELF (EM:40)

Tags: android, boost, android-ndk

**UPDATE:** I've noticed that console output is giving me:

```
Error while executing 'C:\Users\bowli\Tools\Android\android-ndk\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\bowli\Documents\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\CDP_AR1\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\bowli\Documents\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\CDP_AR1\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=mips NDK_ALL_ABIS=mips NDEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/bowli/Documents/Projects/AndroidStudioProjects/CDP_AR1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\bowli\Documents\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\CDP_AR1\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib C:/Users/bowli/Documents/Projects/AndroidStudioProjects/CDP_AR1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips/libcdpp_jni.so}
```

Notice

> APP_ABI=mips NDK_ALL_ABIS=mips

It appears the values from Android.mk and Application.mk are overriden somewhere. For now I'm gonna try to figure out where it happens.

**BASE QUESTION:**

I try to build an Android application with the provided native libraries: boost, MetaIO, etc. The application was fully functional and I'm only supposed to add new functionality to it. However, when I try to build it, I get the following error:

```html
Error:process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

C:/Users/bowli/Tools/Android/android-ndk/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/mipsel-linux-android/4.6/../../../../mipsel-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\bowli\Tools\Android\android-ndk\android-ndk-r8e\sources/boost/android/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(path.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
C:/Users/bowli/Tools/Android/android-ndk/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/mipsel-linux-android/4.6/../../../../mipsel-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\bowli\Tools\Android\android-ndk\android-ndk-r8e\sources/boost/android/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(path.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)

*the same line over9000 times (around 40 actually)*

C:/Users/bowli/Tools/Android/android-ndk/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/mipsel-linux-android/4.6/../../../../mipsel-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\bowli\Tools\Android\android-ndk\android-ndk-r8e\sources/boost/android/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(path.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
C:\Users\bowli\Tools\Android\android-ndk\android-ndk-r8e\sources/boost/android/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [C:/Users/bowli/Documents/Projects/AndroidStudioProjects/CDP_AR1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips/libcdpp_jni.so] Error 1
```

I'm by no means an expert with native development and configuring it, however surfing the web led me to the conclusion that boost wasn't compiled for the same architecture I'm trying to compile for. Therefore I tried all changing the ABI in Application.mk to figure out the boost target architecture. I tried all the ABIs from the supported ABIs list (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html) and all yield the same error.

Then I tried to change the given boost library for the one compiled specifically for armv7 (https://github.com/emileb/Boost-for-Android-Prebuilt), however this gives me essentially the same error:

```html
C:/Users/bowli/Tools/Android/android-ndk/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/mipsel-linux-android/4.6/../../../../mipsel-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\bowli\Tools\Android\android-ndk\android-ndk-r8e\sources/boost/armeabi-v7a/lib/libboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_53.a(path.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
C:\Users\bowli\Tools\Android\android-ndk\android-ndk-r8e\sources/boost/armeabi-v7a/lib/libboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_53.a: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [C:/Users/bowli/Documents/Projects/AndroidStudioProjects/CDP_AR1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips/libcdpp_jni.so] Error 1
```

My Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI      := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL      := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fpermissive
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
```

Also I had to specify:

```
TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

in my Android.mk, otherwise it wanted to build for mips for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I figured it out.

Somehow my **Gradle build file** for the module **was overriding the ABI specification** to mips.

I ended up adding the following to my build.gradle to solve the problem:

```
android {
...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        ndk {
            // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
            // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

More info: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#link-gradle